# Angularjs $location.path() cannot locate to current router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use angularjs and [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to write a page. And I found my router is not working in current router.

For example:

The current router is `/a/b`, and `$location.path()` or `$location.path("/a/b")` is not working.

If I locate to a new path, `$location.path("/a/c")`, it is working.

Please give me some suggestion about my problem. THANKS.

Comment: check in ur object that path() method is avilable or not .. and post some code as well if u have

Comment: the path() method is avaliable while the path is not equals current path.@AshishRatan

Comment: can u paste ur object here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that current url is

```
/a/b
```

From `UI-Router` perspective it means - some **state** e.g.

```
.state("stateA", { 
  url: "/a/:id" 
  ...
}
```

And UI-Router, will not trigger state change, when we call:

```
$location.path("/a/b")
```

Because that means - **NO** state change. On the other hand, this call

```
$location.path("/a/c") // check the 'c' at the end
```

is changing the :id param of the state, and will cause state reload.

I would say, that the preferred way how to force state change, is to use service `$state` and its method `.go()`

```
$state.go("stateA", params, options)
```

where options could be:

```
{reload: true}
```

which will force even current state reload. Check the doc

#### [$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) service

```
go(to, params, options)
```

> ...
>
> Options object. The options are:

- location - {boolean=true|string=} - If true will update the url in the location bar, if false will not. If string, must be "replace", which will update url and also replace last history record.
- inherit - {boolean=true}, If true will inherit url parameters from current url.
- relative - {object=$state.$current}, When transitioning with relative path (e.g '^'), defines which state to be relative from.
- notify - {boolean=true}, If true will broadcast $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events.
- reload (v0.2.5) - {boolean=false}, If true will force transition even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same state. It differs from reloadOnSearch because you'd use this when you want to force a reload when everything is the same, including search params.

Comment: Is there any way to add the url query like `$location.search(key, value)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not experienced with $location. Maybe check the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location. I am using the UI-Router stuff only. And it is enough. I would suggest, try to understand it in more details... to learn the principles, and maybe you also won't need the $locaiton. I'd say $state.go should be enough ... good luck sir ;)